# PDF.JS Cross Domain

Tags: cross-domain, azure-blob-storage, pdf.js

I am attempting to use [PDF.JS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) in order to render user's PDFs in the browser.

We store the PDF files in Azure Blob Storage and we have CORS & SAS to allow our front-end to interact directly with Blob for upload/download.

I have tested our setup with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and **Chrome** is the only browser to fail retrieving the file. The errors I get are related to unsafe headers, the exception below I know results from the inability to read the `Content-Range` header.

`Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Encoding"`

`Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Range"`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at NetworkManager_onStateChange [as onStateChange]`

The response headers from Azure look like:

`Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept-Ranges,Content-Range,Content-Encoding,Content-Length
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tracemonkey.pdf
Content-Length: 65536
Content-Range: bytes 0-65535/1016315
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 15:31:33 GMT
Etag: "0x8D49632DD6406EC"
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 May 2017 16:54:17 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-request-id: 56258985-0001-0062-15d9-c8130c000000
x-ms-server-encrypted: false
x-ms-version: 2015-12-11`

[This is our setup for Blob Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP0f7.png)

Can anyone help me figure out what additional configuration I need to provide to Azure Blob Storage to get this working in **Chrome**?

Comment: Does HTTP range request work with just XHR? Try with just "Range: bytes=0-65535" header and responseType = 'arraybuffer'; (Once that works then it makes sense to dig into PDF.js)

Comment: @async5 This works in chrome
https://jsbin.com/nopuzineno/1/edit?js,console

Comment: (Fails for me with 403) but can you also try that in a web worker?

Comment: Sorry, the Shared Access Signature expired. I have created a longer lasting SAS so you shouldn't have that problem again.

Using a web worker works for me in Chrome. https://jsbin.com/kozepeqiho/edit?js,console

Comment: if I try to access the `Content-Range` header, I get 'Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Encoding"' though

Comment: I checked http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fslopedev.blob.core.windows.net%2Fbdea8372-50a3-4aa0-aca0-9ff4971e34cc%2F8179041a-67ec-4df2-a5b8-613fd2b0c199%3Fsv%3D2016-05-31%26ss%3Db%26srt%3Dsco%26sp%3Dr%26se%3D2017-06-10T17%3A03%3A33Z%26st%3D2017-05-10T09%3A03%3A33Z%26spr%3Dhttps%26sig%3DRYv1yEGLhy46vy1wREGLB%252FPHAXb3d6Bw2cuRX8yKnbI%253D and it works fine.

Comment: What browser are you using? It works just fine in Safari & Firefox but with Chrome I get the errors in my OP.

Comment: It's weird -- before I posted I checked link in Chrome (and also Canary). Now it's failing... for your example as well.

Comment: Added my answer below, PEBKAC ftw. Thank you so much for digging in and trying to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a bit of PEBKAC. I will leave my settings here for anyone else that comes along. We had an application running that set `ExposedHeaders=*` and `AllowedHeaders=*` every time we would `new` our blob service class. So, every time I went into our portal to update the configs, the app would come in after me and change it back.

The settings that work are as follows:

```
{
    Cors: {
        CorsRule: [
            {
                AllowedOrigins: [‘*’],
                AllowedMethods: [‘GET’, ‘PUT’, ‘DELETE’],
                AllowedHeaders: [‘Accept-Ranges’, ‘Content-Encoding’, ‘Content-Length’, ‘Content-Type’, ‘Range’, ‘Authorization’,'x-ms-blob-content-type', 'x-ms-blob-type', 'x-ms-version'], // x-ms headers for upload
                ExposedHeaders: [‘Accept-Ranges’, ‘Content-Range’, ‘Content-Encoding’, ‘Content-Length’, ‘Content-Type’],
                MaxAgeInSeconds: Constants.timeout,
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Thanks @async5 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

set this rules,working on same issue

```
<Cors>      
      <CorsRule>  
            <AllowedOrigins>http://www.contoso.com, http://www.fabrikam.com</AllowedOrigins>  
            <AllowedMethods>PUT,GET,POST</AllowedMethods>  
            <AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-abc,x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-target*</AllowedHeaders>  
            <ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-customheader,x-ms-meta-data*</ExposedHeaders>  
            <MaxAgeInSeconds>200</MaxAgeInSeconds>  
    </CorsRule>  
<Cors>
```